# Type error :cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')

Tags: reactjs, class

While Iam trying to work with events in ReactJs I am getting the error
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')"

here is my code

```
<PhoneInput
      placeholder="Enter phone number"
      value={this.state.phone}
      onChange={(e)=>this.onSelectChange(e)} />
```

The "PhoneInput" is a package, here is link for packkage readme
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input
here is my react function

```
onSelectChange(e){
        console.log(e.target.value);
     }
```

why is Error coming can anyone please find it and help me correct it

Comment: Whatever `PhoneInput` is (which you should include in your question) must not pass an event to it's change handler prop.

Comment: can you show what PhoneInput is? because you're sending ```(e)=>this.onSelectChange(e)``` as a prop. but the event should be called within the PhoneInput component

Comment: Updated the question link is included for PhoneInput

Comment: based on the edit, can you just send the function without a callback, like this: ```onChange={this.onSelectChange}```? also seems like the package only needs the set state as oppose to a method

Comment: @DavidGrosh thanks it solved the problem but i did not understand when to set the callback like this.functionName(e) and when not to, in such cases??

Comment: anytime you add a parenthesis at the end of a method it calls that method when rendering the code, but if you add a callback it will not. so the only time you would need to do that, is if you're sending another parameter to the method aside from the event